# Proving a Set is a Subset of another (with functions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

we have 
$A =\{m ∈ \mathbb{Z}|m=6r-5,r ∈  \mathbb{Z}\} $ and 
$B = \{n ∈  \mathbb{Z}| n= 3s+1, s ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$ 
prove $A ⊆ B$

I have
  Proof: suppose $A = \{m ∈ \mathbb{Z}|m=6r-5,r ∈  \mathbb{Z}\}$,  
$B = \{n ∈  \mathbb{Z}| n= 3s+1, s ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$
suppose P.B.A.C integers x ∈ m and y ∈ n
by substitution $x=6r-5$ and $y=3s+1$, where $r$ and $s ∈ \mathbb{Z}$
and.. I have no idea where to go. should I set these equal to eachother? I have no clue

Comment: Solve  for s in the following equation.  $6r - 5 = 3s+1$ then notice that $s$ will be an integer

Comment: What on earth is P.B.A.C.?

Comment: Particular but arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: @Slowly_Learning Ah, interesting. I've never seen that abbreviation before, and I wouldn't consider it standard. I would go so far as to say that it's not useful either: why write, for example, "let $n$ be a particular but arbitrarily chosen integer" when one can instead just write "let $n$ be an integer"?

Comment: I asked my teacher the same thing (:

Answer (score 2):

Let $m \in A$, $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $m=6r-5$. Then $m=6(r-1)+1=3(2(r-1))+1 $, and so $m \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in A$ iff $(x-1)/6\in \Bbb Z$.

$x\in B$ iff $(x-1)/3\in \Bbb Z$.

Therefore $x\in A\implies (x-1)/6\in \Bbb Z \implies (x-1)/3=2\cdot (x-1)/6\in \Bbb Z \implies x\in B.$